# S3 Interfaces for Backup, etc

Tags: linux, backup, amazon-s3

Since none of the S3 "file systems" are compatible right now, what s3 gateway tool do you recommend for mounting a remote S3 bucket for backups? I've been using S3FS, but I've heard a lot of people complaining about the poor quality of the code; I haven't gone through a formal code review of my own yet. What other tools are you happy with?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm running Linux here. Windows compatibility would be nice, but not essential

Comment: Related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/184717/best-remote-mounted-filesystem-based-on-s3

Answer (score 8):

I'm really happy with [Jungledisk](http://www.jungledisk.com/) which provides a WebDAV interface to S3. You can simply use it for mounting filesystems, or use the included backup features (which uses rsync for incremental backups). Great support too :)

Answer (score 5):

The S3 support in [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) worked fairly well for a company I was working for.  It didn't "mount" the filesystem as such, but it did do nicely encrypted backups.

Answer (score 4):

[Deja Dup](https://launchpad.net/deja-dup) is a new program to back up to Amazon S3; it's a GUI frontend to [duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/) and may work well with your existing plans. Packaged in Ubuntu, but I haven't tried it yet.

```
Package: deja-dup
Description: Backup utility
 Déjà Dup is a simple backup program. It hides the complexity of
 doing backups the 'right way' (encrypted, off-site, and regular)
 and uses duplicity as the backend.
 .
 Features:
  * Uses Amazon S3, an SSH server, or a local folder as a backup location
  * Securely encrypts your data
  * Schedules regular backups
  * Integrates well into your GNOME desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

JungleDisk mount via fuse has been nice, I've not seen any faults with it although haven't used it all that much.  It's not free however.

Answer (score 2):

I have to indulge in a bit of self-promotion and mention my [shaback](http://hewgill.com/journal/entries/445-backup-solution-ideas) utility (also [on github](http://github.com/ghewgill/shaback/tree/master)), which is a Python script to back up files to Amazon S3. It's currently usable but incomplete; while it successfully backs up files, it lacks an automatic restore function (restore must be done manually at the moment).

Shaback stores files in a content-addressable way (so duplicated content is not stored twice), inspired by the Git storage mechanism. It doesn't attempt to expose the S3 storage backend as a filesystem.

Comment: not at all what I'm looking for, but +1 for a nice idea

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [s3fslite](http://github.com/russross/s3fslite). I haven't tried it myself yet but it looks promising. If you do give it a go can you please post your findings?

Answer (score 1):

[S3QL](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql) has been designed specifically for backups on S3 and might well be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a windows/Linux gui app called duplicati that will do remote encrypted backups to S3.  Recent builds have support for backup of locked files on Windows.  It is mono based.